# Extracting linear trends from a dataset

Tags: linear-regression, machine-learning-model, pattern-recognition

Consider a sensor measurement *f* that varies with both temperature *T* and the properties of the fluid being measured. The temperature changes through each day and the fluid properties can be assumed to vary less frequently. If I cross plot the data in Excel then by eye I can very easily draw a straight line through some points and translate that line horizontally and "voila" that same line fits through other clusters of plots. So if that line has slope -1/a then all I need to do instead of plotting *f* versus time I actually plot *f + a T* versus time I get a curve which does not have the temperature dependence and is now indicative of fluid property. Cool.

So my question is how to automate this extraction of *a*. My plan today is to set objective function as the L1 norm of the derivative of the time series and minimize over *a* as that might give a time series of many points with almost zero derivative and a few jump discontinuities where it decides the fluid has changed [as opposed to an L2 that would smear everything out].

But my thoughts are that this feature extraction is likely already covered in some text book somewhere and what I am really missing is the better vocabulary to look it up :-)

Any suggestions? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

OK, I am happy with this. I define a "neuron" to be 2/pi*arctan(lambda*(date-date0)) and have about 99 neurons with steadily increasing date0. If I write any time series as a sum of these neurons then effectively that creates a smooth, piecewise constant approximation to that time series, which is what I'm after. So I add to those neurons an extra "neuron" which is measured temperature data giving me 100 neurons and then a simple L2 optimization to find the best fit of the whole shebang.[image: fit to data]

Answer (score 0):

In case you can treat the properties as discrete variables (aka "dummies", "factors", "one-hot"), you can use linear regression to decompose the effects. Viz. you estimate a "straight line" for each of the properties.

```
# Data
df = data.frame(y=c(1,2,3,5,6, 10,12,13,15,16),prop=c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1),temp=c(5,6,7,8,9,6,7,8,9,10))

# Plot data
plot(df$temp[df$prop==1], df$y[df$prop==1],xlim=c(4,10),ylim=c(0,16),xlab="temp",ylab="y")
lines(df$temp[df$prop==1], df$y[df$prop==1])
lines(df$temp[df$prop==0], df$y[df$prop==0], col="blue")
```

[image]

```
# Linear regression
reg = lm(y~temp+prop,data=df)
summary(reg)


Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
  -0.4   -0.2    0.0    0.2    0.4 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -6.40000    0.55032  -11.63 7.85e-06 ***
temp         1.40000    0.07559   18.52 3.32e-07 ***
prop         8.40000    0.22678   37.04 2.72e-09 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.3381 on 7 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9971,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9963 
F-statistic:  1222 on 2 and 7 DF,  p-value: 1.245e-09


# Prediction for "prop" 1, 0
pred0 = predict(reg,newdata=df[df$prop==0,])
pred1 = predict(reg,newdata=df[df$prop==1,])

# Add prediction to plot
lines(df$temp[df$prop==1], pred1, col="red")
lines(df$temp[df$prop==0], pred0, col="purple")
```

[image]

So you get one "predicted line" per `prop`.

For `prop=0` this would be calculated like $-6.4 + 1.4 * temp + 0 * 8.4$.

For `prop=1` this would be calculated like $-6.4 + 1.4 * temp + 1 * 8.4$.

Essentially: same intercept and slope. Only the "niveau" of the lines is shifted according to the `prop` indicator.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but I don't know the prop indicator. They are also a time series. Indeed determining that is the goal. E.g., you have Freq(time) = Prop(time) + Temp(time)*Coeff + C where Temp(Time) and F(Time) are known. Goal is to choose a Coeff to get Prop(time) to be largely constant and cluster around a few values. Given a value of Coeff, I can define Prop(time) from that equation and I tried minimizing L1 norm of the derivative of Prop(time) and that didnt work.

Comment: Tried something else that didn't work, for a given slope "Coeff" and intercept "C" I can compute a sort of Radon transform by summing all the datapoints that lie close to that line. I was hoping the result would cluster in the Radon transformed space and I could Kmean or something. But nope.... No obvious clustering. I think my problem is that the "eye" does a great job of finding line through the outliers but lots of lines fat through the middle of the blob have plenty of intersection too, maybe more, so the Radon fails.